# What is overalignment of execution regions and input sections?

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I came across code similar to the following today and I am curious as to what is actually happening:

```
#pragma pack(1)
__align(2) static unsigned char multi_array[7][24] = { 0 };
__align(2) static unsigned char another_multi_array[7][24] = { 0 };
#pragma pack()
```

When searching for a reference to the __align keyword in the Keil compiler, I came across this:

> **Overalignment of execution regions and input sections**  There are situations when you want to overalign code and data sections... If you have access to the original source code, you can do this at compile time with the __align(n) keyword...

I do not understand what is meant by "overaligning code and data sections".  Can someone help to clarify how this overalignment occurrs?

Comment: Overalighment might be useful on ARM.  The "load immediate" (MOV) instruction cannot load an entire 32-bit value.  Instead it can load 8 bits at a time, rotated to any position.  For this reason, your code might be trying to cause the address to end in more zero bits, making it easier/faster for the compiled code to load the pointer value to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will naturally "align" data based on the needs of the system. For example, on a typical 32-bit system, a 32-bit integer should always be a single 4-byte word (as opposed to being partly in one word and partly on the next), so it will always start on a 4-byte-word boundary. (This mostly has to do with the instructions available on the processor. A system is very likely to have an instruction to load a single word from memory into a register, and much less likely to have a single instruction to load an arbitrary sequence of four adjacent bytes into a register.)

The compiler normally does this by introducing gaps in the data; for example, a `struct` with a `char` followed by a 32-bit `int`, on such a system, would require eight bytes: one byte for the `char`, three bytes of filler so the `int` is aligned right, and four bytes for the `int` itself.

To "overalign" the data is to request greater alignment than the compiler would naturally provide. For example, you might request that a 32-bit integer start on an 8-byte boundary, even on a system that uses 4-byte words. (One major reason to do this would be if you're aiming for byte-level interoperability with a system that uses 8-byte words: if you pass `struct`s from one system to the other, you want the same gaps in both systems.)

Comment: So in the case of a multidimensional array declared as an unsigned char (like the example above), will each _element_ align to two bytes?

Comment: @embedded_guy: No, just the variable, that is, the array as a whole; since it's an array of one-byte elements, it normally wouldn't require any alignment, but the `__align(2)` requests that it start on a two-byte boundary. It's not possible to align each element to two bytes, because then any client that used the array would have to know that. (When declaring a `struct` type, you can align individual fields because anyone using a `struct` always needs all the `offsetof`s anyway, but for arrays, regular pointer arithmetic is used.)

Comment: +1 Same, I guess somebody didn't like our examples. The struct example you give here didn't even cross my mind. :)

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks for your help.  That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6):

Overalignment is when the data is aligned to more than its default alignment. For example, a 4-byte `int` usually has a default alignment of 4 bytes. (meaning the address will be divisible by 4)

The default alignment of a datatype is quite-often (but not always) the size of the datatype.

Overalignment allows you to increase this alignment to something greater than the default.

---

**As for why you would want to do this:**

One reason for this is to be able access the data with a larger datatype (that has a larger alignment).

For example:

```
char buffer[16];

int *ptr = (int*)&buffer;

ptr[0] = 1;
ptr[1] = 2;
```

By default, buffer will only be aligned to 1 byte. However, `int` requires a 4-byte alignment. If `buffer` isn't aligned to 4 bytes, you will get a misalignment exception. (AFAIK, ARM doesn't allow misaligned memory access... x86/64 usually does, but with performance penalty)

`__align()` will let you force the alignment higher to make it work:

```
 __align(4) char buffer[16];
```

---

A similar situation appears when using SIMD instructions. You will be accessing smaller datatype with a large SIMD datatype - which will likely require a larger alignment.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted.  I found your answer helpful and gave it an upvote.

Comment: +1 for the good example with `int *ptr = (int*)&buffer`. (And to cancel out the anonymous downvoter.)

Answer (score 5):

By overalign, Keil mean nothing more complex than aligning an object to a larger alignment boundary than the data type requires.

See the documentation for [__align](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_BABDFECC.htm): "You can only overalign. That is, you can make a two-byte object four-byte aligned but you cannot align a four-byte object at 2 bytes."

In the case of the linker, you can force an extra alignment onto sections within other binary modules using the `ALIGNALL` or `OVERALIGN` directives. This may be useful for performance reasons, but isn't a common scenario.